# My navigation Drawer is very steal (slow) in android

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

i create navigation drawer in my app. I put 3 menu items in my app. i call Activity in this 3 differnt menu items. when i click on item its motion is very steal(slow). here is my code :-

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    selectedCategoryId = settingHandler.getSettings("default_category")
    val catHandler = CategoryHandler(this)
    val cat = catHandler.getCategoryWithId(selectedCategoryId.toInt())

    /**
     * Navigation drawer item click events
     * @author maulik
     */
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.navFormula -> {
            val intent = Intent(this, FormulaActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
            intent.putExtra("cat", cat)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        R.id.navExam -> {
            val intent = Intent(this, PreExamActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
            intent.putExtra("cat_id", selectedCategoryId)
            //Common.selectedCategoryId = selectedCategoryId
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        R.id.navArticles -> {
            val intent = Intent(this, ArticlesAllActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }

    drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}
```

Comment: Probably because you're using CLEAR_TASK | NEW_TASK instead of switching fragments

Comment: i try remove CLEAR_TASK | NEW_TASK but it still steal(slow) @EpicPandaForce

Comment: Then you should profile what's happening with the method profiler in AS 3.0+

Comment: ok u have another way to solve it? @EpicPandaForce

Comment: I don't know what's slow because you didn't profile it ^_^